# c++ linked list program printing last data item n times

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried to create linked list program on my own. The program compiled without errors, but I am not getting correct results.
I had tried it on GCC and TURBO C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char *name;
    node *link;
};

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    node *start = NULL, *newnode, *temp;
    char nam[10];
    cout<<"Enter number of people:";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter name:";
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nam);
        if(start==NULL)
            newnode = start = new node;
        else
            newnode = newnode->link = new node;
        newnode->link = NULL;
        newnode->name = nam;
    }
    cout<<"\n\tNames:";
    temp = start;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<temp->name;
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    delete newnode;
    delete start;
    delete temp;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:
[Output ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j26rT.jpg)

```
Enter number of people:4
Enter name:qwerty
Enter name:uiop
Enter name:asdf
Enter name:zxcv

        Names:
zxcv
zxcv
zxcv
zxcv
--------------------------------
Process exited after 15.85 seconds with return value 0
```

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: First of all (and this is unrelated to your problem) but technically calling `fflush` in an input-only C `FILE` stream is *undefined behavior*. Secondly (and also unrelated), never ***never*** use `gets`. It's been obsolete for a long time, have been removed from both the C and the C++ standards, and is generally *dangerous!*

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  The Turbo C++ and Borland C++ have good debuggers.  You may also want to diagram (draw) the list as you single step through your code.

Comment: As for your problem, you *do* know about `std::string`? Because that will solve the problem (plus you then need to use safer and better functions than `gets`). Think for a little while where the nodes `name` pointers are pointing? ***All*** of the nodes `name` pointers...

Comment: Not to mention that thing leaks like a sieve.

Comment: Why do you have `newnode = start = new node;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its becouse you let all the nodes point on same array `nam`. Thats reason why all nodes have same name as last entered name. You have to create own memory for every node's `name` pointer (or set `name` in node as automatic array) and then copy `nam` to nodes `name`.

---

Change

```
newnode->name = nam;
```

to

```
newnode->name = new char [strlen(nam) + 1];
strcpy(newnode->name, nam);
```

Also dont forget to `delete[]` allocated memory and read comments under your post to dont use `gets` & `fflush`.

---

Hint:

Instead of char arrays use `std::string`. Its way more easier to use and less error-prone.

```
struct node
{
    std::string name;
    node *link;
};

std::string nam;

std::cin >> nam;

node->name = std::move(nam);
```